# FFMPEG - windows - MJPEG stream - convert to MP4 and re-stream - C# - newbie

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mjpeg, ip-camera

Am a newbie to work with videos and stuff.

Doing a project with a panasonic IP cam (WV-ns-202A) which will be the source of an MJPEG stream.

I need to Display this content on a **ASP.net,C#** web app under **IIS**, as well as store the same in filesystem.

sofar have tried out some **ffmpeg/vlc** stuff not helping much.

(tried #transcoding to flv and save in local filesystem - success
   #transcoding and restream over http - failed
   #transcoding with vlc & streaming (sout) - failed
)

looks like am lost.

Do i must need a meadia server to stream this or can i manage with ffmpeg itself?.
one camera to one user, no users more then that at any point of time.

Any help appreciated - guidence, sample code, links, c#,

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue with the Active X API/SDK provided by Panasonic. Earlier we had issues in finding resources for the particular model.
Thank you!.